# Proving that a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]\backslash \{a_1,...,a_k\}$ has infinite discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\{a_i\}_{i\geq 1}\subset [0,1] $ . If $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]\backslash \{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\}$ is a bijection, then $f$ has infinite discontinuities.

**Proof:** For the sake of contradiction, assume that $f$ has finite discontinuities, call them $\{x_i\}_{1\leq i\leq N}$. Since the amount of $x_i$ are finite, create intervals seperated by $x_i$, call them $A_i=(x_{n_i},x_{n_i+1})$. Now since $f$ has finite discontinuous points, we define $g:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ where $g(x)=\lim_{t\to x}f(t)$ and the image of $A_n$: $V_n:=f(A_n)=(g(x_{n_i}),g(x_{n_i+1}))$. Note that there are $k$ amount of $g(x_i)$ which are equal to $a_j$ for some $j$ . Since $x_i$ are discontinuities, we have that $g(x_i)\neq f(x_i)$ (by the definition of discontinuity). By Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists some $\eta_i \in(x_{k_i},x_{k_i+1})$ such that $f(\eta_i)\in V_j$ for some $j$ . By bijection of $f$, we cannot have that $f(x_i)\in V_j$. Therefore, $f(x_i)$ must all be on the boundaries of $V_i$. That is, it must be the case that $f(x_i)=g(x_j)$ for some $i\neq j$. But we know that there are $N$ amount of $x_i$, yet $N-k$ amount of $g(x_i)$ that $x_i$ could be mapped into by $f$. These two sets with different cardinality cannot create a bijection. Thus contradicting that $f$ is bijective.
(Note that if $f$ has infinite discontinuities, then this could happen because a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ with $k$ elements removed is possible).

**An example of $f$:**

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
   a_{n+k} \text{    , if    } x=a_n \\
   x\text{      otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918181/infinitely-many-discontinuities-for-a-bijective-function-from-0-1-to-0-1) is, essentially, a duplicate of the underlying question.  I can't follow your example.  What does $a_{k+1}$ denote?  There are only $k$ of the $\{a_i\}$, right?

Comment: Should be an infinite sequence, fixed now

Comment: Well, the claim is true for finitely many omissions as well (even a single omission).  But I still don't understand the example.  What does $k$ denote now?  And how could $f$ hit *any* of the $a_i$?  The point was for $f$ to miss those values.