# $A \cup B$ is not connected, when $A$ and $B$ are connected, $A \cap B = \varnothing$ and satisfy C

Tags: general-topology

If $A \subset X$ and $X$ is a topological space, I endow $A$ with the subspace topology.

Let $n \geq 2$.

If $A$,$B$ are connected sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, $A \cup B$ can be connected. Indeed, we can have in this case $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}^n$ : [$A \subset \mathbb{R^n}$, $n \geq 2$, such that $A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n} \setminus A$, and $A$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1962091/a-subset-mathbbrn-n-geq-2-such-that-a-is-homeomorphic-to-mathbb) .

If $A$ and $B$ are convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, $A \cup B$ can also be connected. Indeed, we can take $A = B((-1,0,\cdots,0),1) \cup \{(0,\cdots,0) \}$ and $B = B((1,0,\cdots,0),1)$, where $B(x,r)$ means the open ball of center $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and radius r.

But if $A$,$B$ are closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, $A \cup B$ can't be connected. This is a consequence of the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is normal : we can find open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$, with $U \cap V = \varnothing$.

My questions are :

> (1) What condition $C_1$ weaker than (or different from) "closedness" would
>   force the union of two connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ verifying $C_1$
>   and such that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, to be **not** connected ? And
>   in this case, does it force $A \cup B$ to have exactly 2 connected components
>   ?
>
> (2) What condition $C_2$ weaker than (or different from) "closedness" would
>   force the union of two convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ verifying $C_2$
>   and such that $A \cap B = \varnothing$, to be **not** connected ? And
>   in this case, does it force $A \cup B$ to have exactly 2 connected components
>   ?

For example, if $n = 1$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ seem to be : $\overline{A} \cap B = \varnothing$ and $A \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$.

Comment: In any space the condition $A\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing=B\cap\operatorname{cl}A$ is equivalent to $A\cup B$ not being connected, provided that $A$ and $B$ are non-empty. Sets satisfying the condition are called *separated sets*.

Comment: I was really suspecting it. Thanks.